# How to combine Send Object with ListSend, ClickEvent and Subscribers Objects - sales force marketing cloud SOAP

Tags: sql, soap, google-bigquery, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to combine data between Send, ListSend, ClickEvent and Subscribers Objects Subscribers and ClickEvent I use SubscriberKey, ClickEvent and ListSend I use SendID So I am trying to figure out the correct key to combine the data between those and Send.

How do I do this?

These are the fields I get from Send Object

```
CreatedDate 
ClientID    
EmailID 
SendDate    
FromAddress 
FromName    
Duplicates  
ForwardedEmails 
InvalidAddresses    
HardBounces 
SoftBounces 
OtherBounces    
UniqueClicks    
NumberSent  
NumberDelivered 
NumberTargeted  
NumberErrored   
NumberExcluded  
Unsubscribes    
MissingAddresses    
Subject 
PreviewURL  
SentDate    
EmailName   
Status  
EmailSendDefinitionObjectID 
ID
```

From Subscribers Object

```
ID  
CreatedDate 
ClientID    
EmailAddress    
SubscriberKey   
UnsubscribedDate    
Status  
EmailTypePreference
```

From ClickEvent

```
Client_ID   
CreatedDate 
ModifiedDate    
SendID  
SubscriberKey   
EventDate   
EventType   
BatchID 
URLID   
URL
```

I am not 100% sure what ID should I join with what ID to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send.ID -> ClickEvent.SendID

ClickEvent.SubscriberKey -> Subscribers.SubscriberKey

In terms of order of retrieval, I would start with Send, join to CickEvent, then join to Subscribers.

I think you'll ultimately find that this route for retrieving data from SFMC doesn't scale very well.  If this is more than just a one-off, I'd suggest starting with a [Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5) and loading the data into an external database.

Also, for SFMC specific questions, I'd recommend posting in [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure about this part: Send.ID -> ClickEvent.SendID
Yes you are on the spot here. it doesn't scale really well. 
I`ll take a look at Tracking Extract